# JavaFX - Application: Only main stage is shown from exported jar file while in Eclipse all dialogs are shown, why this difference?

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx

I'm trying to test my JavaFX Desktop Application on Windows and exported a jar file for that. My Eclipse IDE version: 2019-03 (4.11.0)

[Java Class Controllers and FXML files in same directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dRYPj.png)

The code I have runs so far in Eclipse, but when I run the jar file, only the main stage pops up, the next windows don't show up and I get several Error messages on cmd.

I try the creation of the jar file with the two options. The standard "export" from eclipse and then "JAR file" ...

[jar01](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LTzW8.png)

[jar02](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7o9JL.png)

[jar03](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AMnut.png)

[jar04](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uDrDG.png)

Or with Efxclipse - Ant Wizard.

[build.fxbuild](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rf7yx.png)

With both the result is the same...

This is an extract of my main class, which generates the "main stage", the only one that runs from the jar:

```
private static Stage primary;

public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    try {


        primary = primaryStage;
        primaryStage.setTitle("Unicon Automation Tool");
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 278, 143));

        primaryStage.setResizable(false);
        primaryStage.setMaximized(false);

        // primaryStage.resizableProperty().setValue(Boolean.FALSE);
        primaryStage.show();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

And this some code from one Controller Class for the subsequent Stage:

```
private static Stage mainMenu;

private void handleNextAction(ActionEvent event) {

    Window owner = next.getScene().getWindow();

    if (console.isSelected()) {

        Main.goBack();
        Main.setPresentationMode(0);
        Test.test();

    }

    else if (ui.isSelected()) {
        Main.goBack();
        Main.setPresentationMode(1);

        try {
            Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("firstMenu.fxml"));

            mainMenu = new Stage();

            mainMenu.setTitle("Unicon Automation Tool");
            mainMenu.setScene(new Scene(root,441, 218));

            //mainMenu.resizableProperty().setValue(Boolean.FALSE);
            mainMenu.setResizable(false);
            mainMenu.setMaximized(false);
            mainMenu.show();


        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }



    }

    else
        AlertHelper.showAlert(Alert.AlertType.ERROR, owner, "Error!", "You must select one of the options!");

}
```

Expected is that the Application's windows appear as they do in Eclipse IDE, but after I run the jar file, only the main stage appears and after click next, I get this Error message:

```
> Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.RuntimeException: java
.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1774)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(FXMLLoader
.java:1657)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(Comp
ositeEventHandler.java:86)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventH
andlerManager.java:238)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventH
andlerManager.java:191)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(C
ompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDis
patcher.java:58)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispat
chChainImpl.java:114)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDis
patcher.java:56)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispat
chChainImpl.java:114)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDis
patcher.java:56)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispat
chChainImpl.java:114)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
        at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
        at javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:8411)
        at javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Button.java:185)
        at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(Bu
ttonBehavior.java:182)
        at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorS
kinBase.java:96)
        at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorS
kinBase.java:89)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.h
andleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:218)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(Comp
ositeEventHandler.java:80)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventH
andlerManager.java:238)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventH
andlerManager.java:191)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(C
ompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDis
patcher.java:58)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispat
chChainImpl.java:114)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDis
patcher.java:56)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispat
chChainImpl.java:114)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDis
patcher.java:56)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispat
chChainImpl.java:114)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
        at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
        at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
        at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3757)
        at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1500(Scene.java:3485)
        at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1762)
        at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2494)
        at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotificatio
n.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:394)
        at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotificatio
n.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:295)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEve
nt$358(GlassViewEventHandler.java:432)
        at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(Quantum
Toolkit.java:389)
        at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(Glas
sViewEventHandler.java:431)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:555)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:937)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$152(WinApplication.ja
va:177)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1769)
        ... 48 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Location is required.
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3207)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3175)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3148)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3124)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3104)
        at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:3097)
        at application.MainMenuController.handleNextAction(MainMenuController.ja
va:70)
        ... 58 more
```

Comment: Is `firstMenu.fxml` in your jar file? Do you see it "checked" while selecting what to export (jar02 image)? It is good to check resources before using them. Here it looks `getClass().getResource("firstMenu.fxml")` returns null.

Comment: Hello Piro, yes, I checked and that file is "checked" during selecting what to export and in the resulting jar file.

Comment: I updated the screenshot (jar02 image) so you can see it too :)

Comment: @LuisP. In your Java source it is called `firstMenu.fxml`, while in your jar it is `firstmenu.fxml` (note the capital 'M').

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could test today the code and the comment of @helospark was the right answer. After matching the name of the .fxml file in the source code and export the jar file, the application was working as expected. Yet strange that Eclipse IDE wasn't sensitive to the capital 'M'

Comment: just curious: why do you expect eclipse to bark on the spelling of names (in the string vs. the resource)? Is there any plugin that does this type of extended spell-checks?

Comment: Actually what I found curious is that in the Eclipse environment it works and then exported, not,  and that the name of the .fxml file was the reason for the problem. In my mind I expected a notification of this lack of match or "does not exist", as with the names of classes or other resources such as images I use in the project, but if it is generally known that this is not how Eclipse works with .fxml files, the truth I did not know it.